# rollback in laravel in update some data in migration table laravel

Tags: laravel

When I add some data in my laravel database table
and rollback . its shom some problem and not rollback all data in my database.
Which is the best command in laravel migrate rollback ?

Comment: did you tried `php artisan migrate:reset` command

Answer (score 0, accepted):

is so easy !!!

use this command : php artisan migrate:fresh ;
It drop your sql  table data add migrate your new  database table